# $T$ is nice $\Rightarrow T|_U$ is nice

Tags: linear-algebra

The following question arose as I was trying to solve a problem someone else had posed on here. I couldn't think of a satisfactory answer, although it seems pretty obvious:

Let $T$ be an operator on $V$, a finite-dimensional vector space, and let $U$ be a given nonzero subspace of $V$ that is invariant under $T$, so that $T|_U$ makes sense.

Suppose further that $T$ is 'special' in some way: $T$ might be diagonalisable, or maybe (if $V$ is an inner-product space) $T$ belongs to the self-adjoint operators or the positive operators or the isometries. What is the simplest way to prove that $T|_U$ shares the special property of $T$ (i.e., that $T|_U$ is diagonalisable etc.)?

A related conjecture: Supposing $T$ is diagonalisable (and $U$ is $T$-invariant as above), prove that $U = $ null$(T - \lambda I)$, where $\lambda$ is some eigenvalue of $T$.

Comment: The conjecture is wrong. $U$ could be a proper subspace of an eigenspace, or a direct sum of (subspaces of) eigenspaces to different eigenvalues, for example.

Comment: You're quite right. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The statement is obviously not true for any natural property of $T$.

For example take nice $T$ to have $\det T = 1$. Then $\left(\begin{smallmatrix}-1&0\\0&-1\end{smallmatrix}\right)$ is nice, but the restrictions on the components are not. This is also a counterexample for your related conjecture.

I wonder what the category theoretic description of the properties which fulfil your claim is.

Comment: No, that's true… I don't know any category theory, but by 'special' I suppose I really meant operators that have a nice matrix with respect to some basis.

Answer (score 0):

You can just choose a basis for $U$ and then extend it to a basis for $V$. Then all what you have mentioned can easily be proved, except perhaps your conjecture. I shall think more about the conjecture a bit later.

Comment: Really? I don't quite follow. If $T$ is diagonalisable say, how can you ensure, when you choose a basis for $U$, that you only choose eigenvectors of $T$?

Comment: @OwenColman: Choose any basis for U. Then the resulting matrix representation of T is block diagonal. Now, if T is diagonalizable then this matrix can be diagonalized- and hence there must exist such a basis. Alt. Use the Jordan form.

Comment: So given an arbitrary basis for $U$, we extend it to a basis of $V$ in such a way that we only choose eigenvectors of $V$? I've no doubt that works in practice. For me though the issue is that the diagonalisability of an operator $T$ on a certain domain means precisely that 'There exists a basis…' of that domain with respect to which $T$ has a nice matrix. I don't know of any result that says you can extend a given basis of a subspace in the way you describe; although that's not to say there isn't one. Thanks anyway, I'll keep thinking about it.

Answer (score 0):

Let say $T\ge 0  $ so $ <Tv,T>\ge 0 \space \ \forall v\in V$. Particularly $<Tv,T>\ge 0 \space \ \forall v\in U$. Thus $T|_U$ is positive. Similarly one can show $T|_U$ is self-adjoint provided $T$ is self-adjoint.